# Two sets of validation for two popup panels in one ASP page, Unable to submit

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have two Modalpopup panel in one page, one is create , the other is edit current.

`<input type="submit" name="ButtonUpdateLicense" value="Update" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ButtonUpdateLicense&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ButtonUpdateLicense" tabindex="0">`

is automatically added after validations are created. But when the validations in first popup panel haven't completed, I cannot submit the second.  Is there any way to separate the two panels? One possible solution is when I close the first popup, set the value to default. Any decent solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use [Validation Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  This way you can specify that only certain validations fire when you click a certain button.